# Nginx proxy setup

Tags: proxy, nginx, request, sinatra

Hey guys I have a trouble with nginx proxy.

I want to setup it to redirect all requests to one external site (already have that).

But except the request on domain hg.mydomain.com these request I want to redirect to localhost:4567 (sinatra app lives there)

But that doesnt work

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    tcp_nodelay        on;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";


    server {
       listen       80;
       server_name  *.hg.mydomain.com;

       location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4567/;
       }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://sb.mydomain.com;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Shoebox-Host $host;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd want http://hg.mydomain.com to point to the Sinatra app you would want to change the line

```
       server_name  *.hg.mydomain.com;
```

to

```
       server_name  .hg.mydomain.com;
```

or

```
       server_name  hg.mydomain.com;
```

Also, you might want to add `default_server` to your `listen` for the default server. Read more about that here: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#listen